# Unsupported gpu with nvcc fatal

Tags: makefile, cmake, cuda, gpu, nvidia

when i run `make`

I got

```
nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'
     nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'
    CMake Error at libgromacs_generated_nbnxn_cuda.cu.o.Release.cmake:219 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/user/Desktop/gromacs-2019.6/build/src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/mdlib/nbnxn_cuda/./libgromacs_generated_nbnxn_cuda.cu.o
```

I've nvidia rtx 2060 with ubuntu 18.4.5 and cuda-11.1

if there is anything i should write please tell me

**Edit**

line 219 of `Makefile` is

```
# Target rules for targets named missing-phys-val-phys

# Build rule for target.
missing-phys-val-phys: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 missing-phys-val-phys
.PHONY : missing-phys-val-phys

# fast build rule for target.
missing-phys-val-phys/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/missing-phys-val-phys.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/missing-phys-val-phys.dir/build
.PHONY : missing-phys-val-phys/fast
```

**Edit 2**

when i ran

```
cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_MDRUN_ONLY=on -DGMX_FFT_LIBRARY=fftw3    
-DGMX_MPI=off -DGMX_GPU=on -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install
```

i got

```
-- /usr/bin/nvcc standard error:  'In file included from /usr/include/host_config.h:50:0,
             from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:78,
             from <command-line>:0:
 /usr/include/crt/host_config.h:121:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported!
#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 6 are not supported!
 ^~~~~
```

Comment: Change the makefile so it doesn't try to compile for architectures not supported in CUDA 11

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: It's harder to tell you what to do without seeing the `Makefile`.  Find lines that include either `compute_30` or `sm_30` and remove those.  Don't remove the whole line, just remove the switches that reference these.  For example if you see `nvcc ... -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 ...`, just remove the `-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30` part.  Yes, I'm aware that your `Makefile` probably doesn't look exactly like that, and may even be using variables for these, which is why I said it's harder to give instructions without seeing the `Makefile`.

Comment: Why do you use `cmake` tag? If you are trying to build CMake project, then you need to tell which exact project you are building (or show the code of that project).

Comment: if this is from `cmake`, then you will need to find the switch usage in your `CMakeLists.txt` file, or similar, rather than `Makefile`

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thanks for helping and replying, i'm new to use the make command, i'm trying to install gromacs. can I share Makefile here or which line should i share?

Comment: perhaps the best thing for you to do is to update to gromacs 2020.4, see [here](http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/2020.4/release-notes/2020/2020.4.html) "CUDA 11.0 supported¶
A build with CUDA 11.0 now configures and passes tests. Building with CUDA 11.0 means that hardware with CC 3.0 is no longer supported, while CC 8.0 can now be used."

Comment: ok i will try it and hope to work .. thanks so much for your time

Comment: @RobertCrovella still got same error after make command

Comment: perhaps you have not cleaned up your workspace very well.  You'll need to start over at the beginning, install gromacs 2020.4 in a new directory/environment, then start the whole process over again with cmake as indicated [here](http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/current/install-guide/index.html#quick-and-dirty-installation)

Answer (score 3):

For building GROMACS on CUDA 11.x, use GROMACS 2020.4 or later and use a fresh, clean build.

In a fresh, empty directory on linux, with CUDA 11.1 installed, following [these directions](http://manual.gromacs.org/documentation/current/install-guide/index.html), I did:

```
mkdir gmxtest
cd gmxtest
wget --no-check-certificate http://ftp.gromacs.org/pub/gromacs/gromacs-2020.4.tar.gz
tar xfz gromacs-2020.4.tar.gz
cd gromacs-2020.4
mkdir build
mkdir install
cd build
cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_MDRUN_ONLY=on -DGMX_FFT_LIBRARY=fftw3 -DGMX_MPI=off -DGMX_GPU=on -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../install
make
```

and I didn't have any trouble with the `make` command.  For example it was definitely using `nvcc` to compile CUDA code successfully:

```
...
[ 30%] Generating baseversion-gen.cpp
[ 30%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/nbnxm/cuda/libgromacs_generated_nbnxm_cuda.cu.o
[ 30%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/nbnxm/cuda/libgromacs_generated_nbnxm_cuda_data_mgmt.cu.o
[ 30%] Building NVCC (Device) object src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/nbnxm/cuda/libgromacs_generated_nbnxm_cuda_kernel_F_noprune.cu.o
...
```

Note, I'm not suggesting the above is the **exact** recipe you should use.  In particular, modify the `-Dxxx` switches passed to the `cmake` command to match your desired build configuration.

Comment: really thanks for your time , i followed your stepls and got CMake Error at cmake/gmxManageNvccConfig.cmake:182 (message):
  NVCC/C++ compiler combination does not seem to be supported.  CUDA
  frequently does not support the latest versions of the host compiler, so
  you might want to try an earlier C++ compiler version and make sure your
  CUDA compiler and driver are as recent as possible.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/gmxManageGPU.cmake:208 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:578 (gmx_gpu_setup)

Comment: Yes, this is a different issue now.  Probably wouldn't be able to comment further unless you post your exact `cmake` command, just like I have posted my exact `cmake` command.

Comment: i edit the post with new issue , Thanks for helping

Comment: you appear to have multiple versions of CUDA installed on this machine, and gromacs with this build method is now finding one that is not CUDA 11.  CUDA 11 supports at least up through gcc/g++ 8.x, so that warning is coming from an older version of CUDA, probably installed via `apt-get install`.   It's evident that cmake is finding `/usr/bin/nvcc` instead of `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc` or `/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin/nvcc`  Follow the instructions [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#mandatory-post) carefully (9.1.1 only), then repeat the cmake command.

Comment: alternatively, try adding this to your `cmake` command: `-DCUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-11.1`

Comment: i got  The CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:

    /usr/bin/c++

  is not a full path to an existing compiler tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem installing gromacs 2018.3 in a computer with GTX1650, with NVCC (CUDA 11.0).

CMake could also not generate *"build\src\gromacs\CMakeFiles\libgromacs.dir\mdlib\nbnxn_cuda.\libgromacs_generated_nbnxn_cuda.cu.o"*

I found that in *gmxManageNvccConfig.cmake* is not stated the sm_75 which is the architecture of GTX1650. So, to solve this I copied an updated version (gromacs 2020.4) of this file that contains the architecture sm_75 to the same folder "gromacs-2018.3\cmake" and the problem was solved.